# If condition fails but the body statement is executing in components apex controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

I have written a if condition to validate input ofpricelist to be choosen as USD if posting country is not india and selling country is india.

But even though my if condition is failing it displays error.

Can anyone help me to solve the issue.

Apex class

```
@AuraEnabled
Public static Id saveAccount(apttus_proposal_proposal__c qu,String billingAddr,String postingAddr){
   Product_PriceList__c pr = [select id,name from Product_PriceList__c where name='USD']; 
   String str = billingAddr;
   String str1 = postingAddr;
   String PostCountry;
   List<String> res = str.split('`');
   List<String> res1 = str1.split('`');
   System.debug(res);
    if(res[0]!=null){
      qu.FinalBillingStreet__c = res[0];  
    }
    if(res[1]!=null){
      qu.FinalBillingCity__c = res[1];  
    }
    if(res[2]!=null){
         qu.FinalBillingCountry__c = res[2];
    }
    if(res[3]!=null){
        qu.FinalBillingState__c = res[3];
    }
    if(res[4]!=null){
        qu.FinalBillingPinCode__c = res[4];
    } 
    if(res1[0]!=null){
      qu.FinalPostingStreet__c = res1[0];  
    }
    if(res1[1]!=null){
      qu.FinalPostingCity__c = res1[1];  
    }
    if(res1[2]!=null){
         qu.FinalPostingState__c = res1[2];
    }
    else
        qu.FinalPostingState__c = '';
    if(res1[3]!=null){
        qu.FinalPostingCountry__c = res1[3];
        PostCountry = res1[3];
    }
    if(res1[4]!=null){
        qu.FinalPostingPinCode__c = res1[4];
    } 
    try {
        if(PostCountry !='India' && qu.Selling_Country__c == 'India' && qu.PriceList__c!=pr.id){
            return 'Error';
        }
        else{
            insert qu;
            return qu.id;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());    
    } 
}
```

Javascript

```
createAccount : function(component, event,helper) {
            var newQuote = component.get("v.quot");
            console.log('Value of new quote');
            console.log(newQuote);
            var valueB = component.get("v.storeRadioValue");
            var valueP = component.get("v.storeRadioValuePosting");
            console.log('Value of selected value from billing');
            console.log(valueB);
            var action22 = component.get("c.saveAccount");
            action22.setParams({ 
                "qu": newQuote,
                "billingAddr": valueB,
                "postingAddr": valueP
            });
            action22.setCallback(this, function(a) {
                   var state = a.getState();
                    var qpId = a.getReturnValue();
                    console.log(qpId);
                    if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                        var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                        toastEvent.setParams({
                            "title": "Success!",
                            "type" : "Success",
                            "message": "The record has been created successfully."
                        });
                        toastEvent.fire(); 
                        window.parent.location = '/' + qpId;
                    }else if(state === "ERROR"){
                              var errorMsg = a.getError()[0];
                               let toastParams = {
                                 title: "Error",
                                 message:" Please choose Pricelist USD if Selling country is India and Posting country is not India!!!",
                                 type: "error"
                                };
                               let toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                               toastEvent.setParams(toastParams);
                               toastEvent.fire();
                              }
                });
            $A.enqueueAction(action22);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because this condition will fail:

String PostCountry;
PostCountry = postingAddr[3];

String postingAddr -> is String, it should be List of String.

Comment: Could just read the error message in Javascript variable - errorMsg

Comment: have edited the code to show you the original functionality